# Аналог kendoGantt в бутстрапе

Tags: bootstrap

Есть такой вот виджет в кендо - http://dojo.telerik.com/@Dmitry05/alUlE (нажимаем Run).

Т.е. речь о вертикальной черте между гридами, потянув влево-вправо за которую можно менять область видимости гридов. Есть ли что-то подобное в бутстрапе? Умные люди говорят что-есть что-то такое в классе panel, но не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

Этот компонент называется вертикальный сплиттер (Vertical **Splitter**).

В `bootstrap` нет такого компонента.

Я знаю такой компонент в **IgniteUI**

http://www.igniteui.com/splitter/basic-vertical-splitter